# Executing system commands in python

Tags: python, sys

I have experience with perl for writing scripts, which made it easy for me executing linux commands by using back-ticks. I was wondering, how can I do this Python ? Is there a special way for capturing the result of a command (output) ?

thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add to urschrei's answer, here's an example (Windows):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '192.168.111.198'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, st
derr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> out, err = p.communicate()
>>> print out

Pinging 192.168.111.198 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.111.198: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.111.198: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.111.198: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.111.198: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.111.198:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

>>> print err

>>> print p.returncode
0
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, specifically the [subprocess.check_call()](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) and/or [subprocess.check_output()](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) commands.

Comment: For backward-compatibility, you might want to be a bit careful with `check_output`, which is only on >=2.7.  Before 2.7, you probably need to use `Popen` with `subprocess.PIPE`